# Firefox mousewheel type event in jquery recognized as resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, jquery-events

I bind window to next events:

```
$(window).on('mousewheel keydown resize', function(ev) {});
```

This code works fine in Chrome, ev.type on mousewheel is 'mousewheel'

However, in Firefox ev.type is 'resize'.

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/m86721ot/2/) (JSFIDDLE is responsive to resize, thus no mousewheel, but can be checked in any other page)

Is there is known bug in FF or I missed something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use following code to get mouse scroll event in firefox.

```
$(window).bind('DOMMouseScroll mousewheel keydown resize', function(ev) {alert(ev.type)})
```

In firefox you will need DOMMouseScroll event.

Here is updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m86721ot/3/).

Answer (score 0):

The mousewheel event does not seem to be supported in firefox according to MDN:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mousewheel

Also when I tested it, mousewheel is not triggering a resize or any event for that matter.